# Outbound link tracking and 'undefined' links

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, flexslider

I've installed the following outbound link tracking code on a website which is working well.

The trouble is it's causing an issue with the dots in an image slider also on the site (using flexslider). When these dots are clicked, they normally move the image slider to that slide, but the link tracking script is causing the page to reload and go to '/undefined' (i.e. www.domain.com/undefined).

```
$(function() {
    $("a").on('click',function(e) {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        if (e.currentTarget.host != window.location.host) {
            _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent("Outbound Links", e.currentTarget.host.replace(':80',''), url, 0);
            if (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey || this.target == "_blank") {
                var newtab = true;
            }
            if (!newtab) {
                e.preventDefault();
                setTimeout('document.location = "' + url + '"', 100);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any tips on how to solve this would be massively appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: It would be better for you to add something to all links to identify as something you want to track, e.g. add a specific `class="analytics"` or `data-analytics="true"` and then use that as part of your selector

Comment: I agree but the challenge is that some of the outbound links come via a third party widget where I can't control the link code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter your selector results or check when href is undefined, which seems to be the case for the dots of the slider, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("a").on('click', function(e) {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        if (url && e.currentTarget.host != window.location.host) {
            _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent("Outbound Links", e.currentTarget.host.replace(':80', ''), url, 0);
            if (e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey || this.target == "_blank") {
                var newtab = true;
            }
            if (!newtab) {
                e.preventDefault();
                setTimeout('document.location = "' + url + '"', 100);
            }
        }
    });
});
```